# Remove first char from each string in an array if the first char is same in each string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

I have an array of strings and what I want to do this is to check if the first `char` in each string is the same. And if it is, remove that `character` from every string and return the new array.

I am doing it like this:

```js
let labels = [
"- Knowledge",
"- Propositional Logic",
"- Inference",
"- Knowledge Engineering",
"- Inference Rules",
"- Resolution",
"- First-Order Logic"
]

let theChar;
let same = true;

for (let index=0; index<labels.length; ++index){
    if (index === 0){
      theChar = labels[index].charAt(0);
      console.log(theChar);
    }else{
      // check if the current label's charAt(0) is the same as theChar
      if(labels[index].charAt(0) != theChar) {
        same = false;
        break;
      }
    }

}

console.log(`SAME: ${same}`)
if(same){
  // remove that element..
  labels = labels.map(ele => ele.substr(1,ele.length).trim());
}

console.log(labels)
```

One other way I thought of was to construct a new array of strings with the first char from each string removed while I am checking for `same`ness condition. And if the loop breaks(the means the first char is not the same in all the strings), so I keep the original array. If the loop does not break, then keep the new array. This way I won't have to traverse the array twice.  (but I will be performing the string operations on every element in this case until I break out of the loop (by `break` statement or when all the elements are done))

Is there any other better way to do this? Or Which one is better from the above two approaches if there are a lot of strings in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just check if every element has the same first char as the first element with `every()`.

And if that succeeds, `map()` the array to get the substring of each element starting after the first char.

```js
let labels = [
"- Knowledge",
"- Propositional Logic",
"- Inference",
"- Knowledge Engineering",
"- Inference Rules",
"- Resolution",
"- First-Order Logic"
];

let result = labels;

if(labels.every(s => s[0] == labels[0][0])) {
  result = labels.map(s => s.substring(1));
}

console.log(result);
```

A few things to learn here:

- You can access a strings specific char using the array access notation `[ ]` instead of `charAt()`
- You can omit the second parameter of `substring()` if you want the rest of the string anyways
- I highly suggest you to read into the most common array functions like `every()`, `some()`, `filter()` and so on. They are really helpful